# Delete empty dataframe with loop in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a serie of different DataFrame in Python. I want to check if each of them is either empty or not and then delete those that are actually empty. I am trying with a loop but none dataframes are actually deleted, also those that are actually empty. Here the example, where *df_A*, *df_B*, *df_C*, and *df_D* are my dataframes and the last one (*df_D*) is empy.

```
df_names = [df_A, df_B, df_C, df_D]
for df_ in df_names:
    if df_.empty: del df_
```

For sure I am missing something quite simple, I hope you can help me with this (probably a bit silly) question.

Comment: You want to remove dataframe from list or want to delete dataframe itself?

Comment: The dataframe itself

Comment: Add plain python tag please. `del` won't help you here.

Comment: Do you have a series or a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python `locals()` function to do this. I would first save the dataframes in a list as `string`:

**Code**

```py
df_names = ['df_A', 'df_B', 'df_C', 'df_D']
for df_ in df_names:
    if locals()[df_].empty:
        del locals()[df_]
```

You can also check if your dataframe has been deleted using the below code:

```py
alldfs = [var for var in dir() if isinstance(eval(var), pd.core.frame.DataFrame)]
for i in alldfs:
    if i[:1] != '_':
        print (i)
```

The above snippet will return all the existing dataframes (excluding the ones defined by python internally)

Comment: Thank you so much @Gary for your kind responde. It worked perfectly!